# LINQ doing individual queries when it should have the data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm really new to LINQ and C#, however have experience with other ORMs. I'm seeing a behavior that I'm not liking, or think I'm not liking, and am trying to figure out how to stop it.

I have a query like ...

```
var query = from x in MyTable
            where myListOfIds.Contains(x.parentId)
            select x;
```

which gives me SQL that looks like this ...

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
    [Extent1].[Blah] AS [Blah], 
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ParentId] IN (1, 2, 3)
-- Executing at 4/20/2018 1:26:08 PM -05:00 
-- Completed in 241 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

That's what I want. It returns 3 rows of data. So when I loop over each row ...

```
foreach (var row in query)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Row ID is " + row.Id.ToString());   
}
```

I can see 3 additional queries like ...

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
    [Extent1].[Blah] AS [Blah], 
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ParentId] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 4/20/2018 1:53:37 PM -05:00
-- Completed in 209 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

I would think that the SQL with the IN clause will have gotten all the data, and no additional queries needed. I've tried .ToList() and .ToArray(), hoping that would prevent the additional queries.

Any hints on how to get all the data in one shot?

Thanks

Comment: Entity Framework does lazy loading which means load on access. If you want one query then make sure to use a .Include 
For more reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @SCFi The OP is not accessing navigation properties.

Comment: Are you using EF or EF Core or LINQ to SQL? Also what database engine? This shouldn't be happening.

Comment: I think we are using EF 6.1.1 ( according to the References) and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently creating an `IQueryable`, which is not materialized into a list of records until you do something with it. In this case, you are iterating over each record and retrieving the `Id`, so it is executing one query per record.

What you could do instead is materialize the entire list of records in one call using `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`, at which point you should have all of the records in memory.

```
var query = (from x in MyTable
    where myListOfIds.Contains(x.parentId)
    select x);

// Note that query is simply an IQueryable at this point,
// so we should execute the query and materialize the data
var records = query.ToList();

foreach (var row in records)
{
    // At this point, records is now a list in memory
    Debug.WriteLine("Row ID is " + row.Id.ToString());
}
```

See [Query Execution (LINQ)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `foreach` should have materialized the query - at least, my LINQ to SQL does. Is EF / EF Core different in that way? From [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-and-linq-to-entities-6-deferred-execution-laziness-loading-and-eager-loading) I see this for EF/EF Core: "Later, when the iterator’s MoveNext method is called for the first iteration, the SQL query is generated and executed. In each iteration, an entity is materialized from the SQL execution result."

Comment: It should, not sure why the OP is seeing something different.

Comment: What you have is pretty much what I've been doing. I was hoping to .ToList() or .ToArray() would indicate I didn't want to lazy load.